# Cordova/Ponegap on iOS7 Getting Connection.CELL in Airplane mode

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I wanted to check whether I had an internet connection in my app before accessing remote content.  However, I was somewhat surprised that when I put the iPhone in Airplane mode, `"navigator.connection.type`" returns `"Connection.CELL"`.  I would have expected `"Connection.NONE"` or `"Connection.UNKNOWN"`. Is this a "feature" or a "bug" and is there anyway to establish you are in Airplane mode in `iOS`? Just to note when on `WiFi` I DO get "Connection.WiFi".

Tested on:

```
Cordova/Phonegap 3.3

iOS 7.0.4 on an iPhone (4S)
```

Comment: This may help you - http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection

Comment: @Suhas - I Had already read that. There is an iOS Quirk "iOS can't detect the type of cellular network connection. navigator.connection.type is set to Connection.CELL for all cellular data."

But I would still have expected "NONE" or "UNKNOWN" in airplane mode - as there isn't a cellular connection at that point.

Comment: I am having the same issue on an iPad Mini Wifi+Cellular on iOS 7.0.6. Any progress or workarounds?